# Git clone from bash script

Tags: git, bash, ssh, git-clone

I am trying to automate my interactions with Git building a script and I am having the following problem.

This works from the command line:

```
git clone git@github.xxxx.com:blablabla/reponame.git /Users/myname/dev/myfolder
```

And now I would like to do the same, but from my script. I have the following:

```
#/bin/bash

repository="git@github.xxxx.com:blablabla/reponame.git"

localFolder="/Users/myname/dev/myfolder"

git clone $repository" "$localFolder
```

that gives me this error

> GitHub SSH access is temporarily unavailable (0x09). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Any light on this will be much appreciated

Comment: You mean `git clone "$repository" "$localFolder"`, I'd hope? Otherwise, you're asking that the contents of both variables be string-split and glob-expanded, and then that the rightmost argument resulting from splitting the former and the leftmost argument resulting from splitting the latter be combined into a single argument with a space between them... which seems like a very silly thing to do.

Comment: So yes, that silly thing I was doing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I think you should add that as an answer, so that this doesn't look like an unanswered question in search, etc.

Comment: @MarkLongair I think it makes more sense than that to just close the question -- it's not something likely to help other people -- but it doesn't look like anyone else is with me on that.

Comment: I had no idea what $a" "$b would do, so even though the question was simple, the answer had merit

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You mean `git clone "$repository" "$localFolder"`, I'd hope?

Running `git clone $repository" "$localFolder` is something quite different:

- Because neither variable is within double quotes, their contents are string-split and glob-expanded; thus, if they contained whitespace (generally, characters within `$IFS`), they could become multiple arguments, and if they contained globs (`*`, `[...]`, etc), those arguments could be replaced with filenames (or simply removed from the generated argument list, if the `nullglob` shell option is enabled)
- Because the space between the two arguments is quoted, they are combined into a single argument before being passed to `git`.

So, for the values you gave, what this script runs would be:

```
git clone "git@github.xxxx.com:blablabla/reponame.git /Users/myname/dev/myfolder"
```

...which is quite different from

```
git clone git@github.xxxx.com:blablabla/reponame.git /Users/myname/dev/myfolder
```

...as it is giving the `/Users/myname/dev/myfolder` path as part of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my case I want to clone all of my GitHub repos (all branches) to backup it in folder. I created a python script to do it located here https://github.com/tisma95/github-clone you can try with it if you want.

Thanks