# How to manage 'server' and 'client' folders within a repo

Tags: git, nginx, deployment

I have a project structure as follows:

```
- client
  - package.json
- server
  - package.json
package.json
```

For development, I will run a npm script from the root's package.json that will start both my 'server' and 'client':

```
 "client": "cd client && npm run dev",
 "server": "cd server && npm run dev",
 "start": "npm-run-all --parallel server client"
```

Currently, there is only one Github repo to which 'server' and 'client' codes are pushed.

Now that I'm deploying the 'server' and 'client' individually to Digital Ocean-- `git clone <server>` to my droplet, and `git clone <client>` to `/var/www/example.com/html` nginx folder-- I'm at a lost as to how I should go about separating them into separate repo which, correct if I'm wrong, is what I'm supposed to do in order to deploy to DO, while still being able to start both of them with a single npm script for local development..

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong but basically you are talking about a single droplet and you want to clone your repo(s) into different directories of this droplet.

I think you have various options to achieve this:

1. Just split up your repo and write a script to clone both repos into the right directory on your droplet (assuming it is a Linux System, write a shell script - I recommend [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857024/git-clone-from-bash-script).
2. Do not split up your repository, clone it into a temporary (not public) directory on your droplet and execute a shell script which copies the right files into the desired directories.
3. In my opinion the best way to achieve this: Think about a CI/CD pipeline. Check out  [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tags/ci-cd?type=tutorials) for further information. And [this is a tool](https://wodby.com/) with DO integration!

Cheers and good luck!